# Convert a format string to timestamp in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timestamp

Before asking this question I have searched stack overflow but found some other language's answer. I did not find a post with Swift.

I have the string `2016-12`,the `time` is `2016-12-01 00:00:00`. I want to convert to a `timestamp`, since `1970` using `Greenwich Mean Time`.

2016-12 → 1480521600.

2016-12 is a string formatted as year-month. I want to convert it to a timestamp

How can I convert it in Swift?

Comment: What timestamp do you want? Do you want it for midnight of the first day of the given month and year? In what timezone? UTC? The user's local timezone? Some other?

Comment: Your update answers part of my question. What about the timezone?

Comment: @rmaddy thanks your remind, and your careful, we should be rigorous.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try this code:

```
var dfmatter = DateFormatter()
dfmatter.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
var date = dfmatter.date(from: "2016-12-1")
var dateStamp:TimeInterval = date!.timeIntervalSince1970
var dateSt:Int = Int(dateStamp)
```

Comment: The format does not match the date string in the question.

Comment: @god is a coder , you should edit your answer to english. because `sof` is face to worldwide.

Comment: Keep in mind that this treats the date as midnight in the user's local timezone.

Comment: sorry,my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it more clear: (SWIFT 3.0 -> 4.1)

```
 let yourDate = "2016-12-01"

 //initialize the Date Formatter
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

 //specify the date Format  
 dateFormatter.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"

 //get date from string 
 let dateString = dateFormatter.date(from: yourDate)

 //get timestamp from Date
 let dateTimeStamp  = dateString!.timeIntervalSince1970
```